# Where are intranet cookies stored in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, intranet

Anyone know where intr**a**net cookies are stored?

e.g. http://example/

n.b. not int**e**rnet cookies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All cookies are stored in the same place.

Comment: I'm running XP SP3 & IE8, when viewing

C:\Documents and Settings\MY USERNAME\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\

All I can see are cookies from FQDN's e.g. http://www.example.org

However I know the cookies are being set, as I can see them using a HTTP tracer (the fiddler).

Comment: Whoops! My mistake, I realised that I was not only looking for intranet cookies but also they are session cookies!

For reference:
It looks as though session cookies are not stored (as such) but only stored in memory. However you can see them (but this might be just because I have the developer toolbar installed) in a hidden directory here: C:\Documents and Settings\MY USERNAME\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5

Notably Content.IE5 cannot even be seen if you turn on show hidden directories, but you can browse to it. In comments of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688956/

Answer (score 0):

EmmEff is correct  - thanks EmmEff :), all cookies are stored in the same place.

However it appears I was looking for session cookies by mistake (which don't appear to be stored).

For reference (I relise this is answering a slightly different question) If you have the IE developer toolbar installed and click "cache" > "View cookie information". It will generate an XML file in a hidden directory:

C:\Documents and Settings\MY USERNAME\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5

(note the IE5 - I have IE8 installed)

The XML file will contain the session cookies.